# react-leaflet-draw - onEditStart/Stop events cumulates when trying to edit multiple featureGroups

Tags: react-leaflet, react-leaflet-draw

I have a React application where a `react-leaflet@2.7.0` + `react-leaflet-draw@0.19.0` map is displaying multiple `FeatureGroup` components containing polygons.
On the right end side of the app is a clickable list of the feature groups names.
The groups can be selectively "activated" by clicking the names, so if a feature group is active, the EditControl therein is rendered. Only one group can be active at a time.

**My problem**

when I switch from one group to another and then click the edit button in `EditControl`, the `onEditStart/Stop` events of the previously active group still fire, along with the new ones. The more I switch between groups, the more events are fired.

**Update:**

The issue seems to be that `EditControl` is never unmounted, even if upon the parent state change it doesn't get rendered. If I add a random `key` prop to it, the issue is resolved, but then other issues occur.

I don't yet have a minimal code example to share, but to give you an idea of the implementation here is a schema:

```
<App>
   <Map>
     <MapContent id="foo">
      <FeatureGroup>
        <EditControl />
      </FeatureGroup>
     </MapContent>
     <MapContent id="bar">
      <FeatureGroup>
        <EditControl />
      </FeatureGroup>
     </MapContent>
   </Map>
   <GroupSelector />
</App>
```

Except `App` (root component), `MapContent` (very basic wrapper: checks if the group is active) and `GroupSelector` (clickable list), all other components are from `react-leaflet` and `react-leaflet-draw`.

**Flow**
On click, `GroupSelector` updates the state of `App` to set an `activeGroupID` (i.e. "foo") and `MapContent` will render its `EditControl` only if its `id` matches the `activeGroupID`

I hope this description makes sense. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How are you passing `activeGroupID` to `MapContent` so it can check if the `id` prop is equal to `activeGroupID?

Comment: @ teddybeard via props (App[state] > Map[props] > MapContent[props]). Then each `MapContent` compares them. Eventually I will implement a `MapContextProvider`, but for now I just want to make it work.